# Is there a standard way to calculate std::hash<T>{}(x) without specifying T explicitly?

Tags: c++, stl

And to infer `T` from `x` instead? Obviously I can declare a function to do this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
size_t get_std_hash(const T& x) {
    return std::hash<T>{}(x);
}
```

The question is in case I've overlooked something, and this function or some variation of it is already in the standard.

Comment: Are you asking if the standard already provides a function that does the same thing as your `get_std_hash`? AFAIK no.

Comment: as an expression? `std::hash<decltype(x)>{}(x)`?

Comment: @Caleth I thought of that, but `x` can be a non-trivial expression, and I want to avoid repeating it for the same reason I don't want to specify `T` in the first place.